# Are functions only in non-object-oriented languages?

Tags: java, oop, function, methods

I was asked to answer this question:

> Where should I put the Javadoc specific comment notation of /** and */
>   if I want to tell the user specifics about a certain instance variable
>   or method?

I answered with:

> Above the function declaration.

The answer was rejected and this was the reason:

> Functions are in non-object-oriented languages. Method is the proper name.

Is this true?

Comment: Yes it is true indeed. In Object Oriented Languages we say the functions as methods.. because that method belongs to that particular object....

Comment: I'd say you were dealing with a terminology nazi...

Comment: this is not true. they are one and the same.

Comment: If this was an interview question, run far far away. People who obsess with trivialities like this are never fun to work with. Consider yourself lucky.

Answer (score 17):

> Are functions found only in non-object-oriented languages?

No. There are object-oriented languages that have functions.  C#, for example, is an object-oriented language but it has *anonymous functions*.

> What are the named procedures which are members of a type typically called in object-oriented languages like Java or C#?

Typically they are properly called *methods*, though this differs from language to language. In Java or C# I would say "method".

In Visual Basic, for example, the distiction is made between *functions* and *subroutines* on the basis of whether or not they return a value, not on the basis of whether they are associated with a type container.

JavaScript, an object-oriented language which uses prototype inheritance rather than class inheritance, typically refers to all of the above as "functions".

> Do people frequently refer to methods as functions when speaking casually about Java or C#?

Yes. Were I writing documentation or a book or a scholarly article then I would be careful to make the distinction. In commonplace parlance though everyone reasonably conversant with the art of computer programming would understand "function" and "method" to be roughly synonyms. I would not have rejected your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any answer which limits this to a specific language is inherently flawed. In addition you must also deal effectively with static methods and subroutines.

Computer science began with the term '**subroutine**'. Small sections of repeatable code which could be executed arbitrarily to perform a common action. Examples are found in early programming languages such as BASIC.

**Functions** were the evolution of subroutines. They take arguments and may or may not return a value. They take some concepts from maths - input, translated to a given output.

With objects we need to be able to call actions on objects and we do this be exposing **methods**. Like functions they take arguments and may or may not return a value.

**Static methods** are designed to act on all possible objects of a class.

The problem is that, pure object-orientated programming leaves no scope for the definition of functions (or indeed subroutines). And languages that evolve to become object orientated often retain syntax from functions to implement methods.

In ***Java*** we resort to using 'Utility' classes to provide functions as `public static` methods. The `Math` class in JavaScript is another example of this.

In ***PHP*** we tolerate the use of the word `function` to define methods.

In ***C++*** we see both functions and methods, neither demarcated. Indeed, C++ makes no reference to methods, calling them *member functions*.

Answer (score 0):

## A function is not bound to a class.

A function is something like `doStuff();`.

A method is like `someThing.doStuff();` or `SomeClass.doStuff();`.

In Java, there is no such thing as a function. They are all methods. i.e.

```
    class Test {

        public static void doSomething() {...}
        public void otherThing() {...}

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            doSomething(); //implied Test.doSomething();
        }

        public Test() {
            otherThing(); //implied this.otherThing();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd argue that this question transcends Java.  In Python, for instance, you can have both functions *and* methods.  Would you want to expand on what a function actually is, and what a method actually is?

Comment: @Makoto yes, but needed FGITW :P

Comment: @SantoshPingale no I'm not

Comment: C++ Standard uses a "member function" term instead of "method"

Comment: @San no, this post has no edits